# RecyclerView Shared Element Transition Not Working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-navigation, android-transitions

My aim : [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtPv4.gif)

[image]

I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@serbelga/shared-elements-in-android-navigation-architecture-component-bc5e7922ecdf) to implement shared element transitions in my app

My Result : [Screen Capture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EMFEjpmXVl6GGgKiq7JqrNuS85azf3HV/view)

**Problem :** **The shared animation is happening**. **But the image in the ItemMovieFragment is coming from top left corner of container.**

Cannot figure out the solution.

Please suggest some solution

Here is the code :

***ItemMovieFragment*** :  [complete code](https://gist.github.com/7phalange7/92a5e9b61f0f561a9366485aa813382b)

```
   class ItemMovieFragment  : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var itemMovieViewModel: ItemMovieViewModel
    private lateinit var args : ItemMovieFragmentArgs

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = FragmentItemMovieBinding.inflate(inflater)


      //  (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()

        sharedElementEnterTransition =    TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)

      
     // rest of the code
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(image_poster,args.itemiId.toString())
        Toast.makeText(context,"id: ${args.itemiId}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
}
```

***ItemMovieFragment - Layout*** : [complete code](https://gist.github.com/7phalange7/b470de1ef44cd3cf218fe74d684f0c5c)

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView2">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_poster"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:imageUrl="@{itemMovieViewModel.movieInf.posterPath}"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/stp" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

***CompletedFragment*** : [complete code](https://gist.github.com/7phalange7/d0ab69b8584bb2d23c7365236b207afd)

```
       class CompletedFragment(private var type : String) : Fragment() {
    
    
        //firebase
        private lateinit var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
        private lateinit var dbReference: DatabaseReference
        private lateinit var firebaseAdapter: FirebaseRVAdapter
        private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            val binding = FragmentCompletedBinding.inflate(inflater)
    
    
    
    
    // rest of the code...
    
    
    
            firebaseAdapter = FirebaseRVAdapter(FirebaseRVAdapter.ItemClickListener { item ->
    
                val id : Int = item.id!!.toInt()
                val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(
                    poster to item.id!!
                )
    
                if(type == TV)
                findNavController().navigate(MyWatchlistFragmentDirections.actionGlobalItemTvFragment(id))
               else
                findNavController().navigate(MyWatchlistFragmentDirections.actionMyWatchlistFragmentToItemMovieFragment(id),extras)  // this is the navigation line for shared animation
    
            }, optionss)
    
            binding.myfirebaseList.adapter = firebaseAdapter
    
            return binding.root
        }
//rest of the code
}
```

***FirebaseRVAdapter*** :

```
 package com.utkarsh.fxn.ui.mywatchlist


class FirebaseRVAdapter(private val clickListener: ItemClickListener , options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<TvFirebase>)
    : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TvFirebase, FirebaseRVAdapter.tvFirebaseViewHolder>(options) {
    class tvFirebaseViewHolder ( private var binding: MywatchlistListItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {


        fun bind(
            tvfirebase: TvFirebase,
            clickListener: ItemClickListener
        ){
            ViewCompat.setTransitionName(binding.poster,tvfirebase.id)  //setting transition name
            binding.tvFirebase=tvfirebase
            binding.clickListener=clickListener
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): tvFirebaseViewHolder {
        return tvFirebaseViewHolder(MywatchlistListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: tvFirebaseViewHolder, position: Int, model: TvFirebase) {
        return holder.bind(model!!,clickListener)
    }

    class ItemClickListener(val listener : (tvfirebase: TvFirebase) -> Unit){

        fun OnClick(tvfirebase: TvFirebase) = listener(tvfirebase)
    }


}
```

***XML of image of item of Completed Fragment*** : [complete file](https://gist.github.com/7phalange7/986a9cc989b9f8b80a03aa75fe57e1d5)

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="114dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            app:imageUrl="@{tvFirebase.poster_path}"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.013"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/smol" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have same transitionName for item and details screen.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="114dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:transitionName="image_poster"
            app:imageUrl="@{tvFirebase.poster_path}"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.013"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/smol" />
```